# MYSQL Divided column value based on row from the same table

Tags: mysql

I have table like this ..

```
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+
| ID        |  Name      | NILAI INDEKS  | SKS    |
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+
|         3 | abc        | 3             |     4  |
|         3 | abc        | 2             |     2  |
|         3 | abc        | 3             |     4  |
|         4 | def        | 2             |     2  |
|         4 | def        | 3             |     4  |
|         4 | def        | 2             |     2  |
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+
```

I want result like this, Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| ID        |  Name      | IPS          | 
+-----------+------------+--------------|
|         3 | abc        | 1,25         |
|         4 | def        | 1,14         |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

IPS = SUM from sks divided by SUM from Nilai Index

---

example :
IPS abc = (4+2+4) / (3+2+3) = 10/8 = 1,25

Comment: So IPS doesn't stand for "INDEKS  PER SKS"!!!

Comment: Anyway, what did you try?

Comment: sorry but I finally found the answer by myself ..

Answer (score 0):

I Found the answer,

```
SELECT
    id,name,
        SUM(sks * nilai)/SUM(sks) AS IPS
FROM
    nilai
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Cool, but this answer doesn't match the question